# Spinning up multiple tmux sessions in bash

Tags: bash, tmux

I have a python script, `my_python_script` that takes an input date.
I have a bash script that calls this python script for a series of dates, within a for loop. I tried creating a named session within the for loop, but this nests tmux sessions:

```
call_runner_date_range() {
    start=$1
    end=$2

    start=$(date -d $start +%Y%m%d)
    end=$(date -d $end +%Y%m%d)

    while [[ $start -le $end ]]
    do
            tmux new -s $start
            start=$(date -d"$start + 1 day" +"%Y%m%d")
            formatted_date=$(date -d $start +%m-%d-%Y)
            python -m my_python_script --analysis-date=$formatted_date
    done
}

call_runner_date_range '2016-12-31' '2019-08-15'
```

I would like to modify this bash script to open a new tmux session for each date (the reason I want to use tmux is so I can monitor the output logs), so that these scripts can run in parallel. How can I do this, and is there a preferable alternative to using tmux?

Comment: Are you just asking for how to use [`send_keys`](https://blog.damonkelley.me/2016/09/07/tmux-send-keys/)?

Comment: @jeremysprofile- tmux was my understanding of the best way to do this, but if you think think your suggestion might be a preferable alternative, can you post that as a solution? I have not used `nohup` or `send_keys` before

Comment: `tmux` seemed like a good solution because I still want to monitor the logs which currently get printed to stdout (edited question to reflect this)

Comment: Sure, but tmux opens an _interactive_ session the program, it's hard to navigate with over 600 running processes. Wouldn't it be easier to just redirect the output of each python script to each unique file in some directory? It would be just `python ... > "some_dir/log_$start.log" &` Or redirect them all to one file, with each line prefixed with unique string for each process.

Comment: `tmux new` doesn't create a *nested* session, because your script can't be moved into a tmux session; any copy of tmux it starts is a child process; UNIX generally doesn't permit reparenting, and while changing stdin/stdout/stderr to point to a different set of FDs is *possible*, it involves a bunch of tricky magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start a process in the background use the `&` as the terminating character of the command. Use `>` to redirect the standard output of a process to a file. For some reference, you could see [bash manual List of commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists) or [bash manual redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) but many resources are available online.

So the script would just become:

```
call_runner_date_range() {
    start=$1
    end=$2

    start=$(date -d $start +%Y%m%d)
    end=$(date -d $end +%Y%m%d)

    while [[ $start -le $end ]]
    do
            start=$(date -d"$start + 1 day" +"%Y%m%d")
            formatted_date=$(date -d $start +%m-%d-%Y)
            python -m my_python_script --analysis-date=$formatted_date > log_$start.log &
    done
}

call_runner_date_range '2016-12-31' '2019-08-15'
```

You can use [`wait`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html) shell builtin to wait for all currently still running background processes in current bash shell. Or, you can save each background job process id PID using `$!` and specify the list of pids you want to wait for.

```
childs=() # bash array, initializing to empty

# then later:
python -m my_python_script --analysis-date=$formatted_date > log_$start.log &
childs+=($!)  # append the background jobs pids name to bash array

# then later
wait "${childs[0]}" # wait for first background job in childs array
wait "${childs[@]}" # wait for all background jobs in childs array
```

Note you may interested in using [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) that can (on most implementations) execute commands in parallel for each line of input or the amazing [GNU `parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) which is just a shell tool to execute multiple jobs in parallel as easy as possible.